# Power of a component in an AC circuit

Tags: ac

So I was asked to find the power absorbed by the 2 ohm element and I found it. But I am confused on why Power is calculated using the voltage at the node instead voltage drop across the 2 ohm resistor.
This question was E.93 in Basic Circuit Analysis, 11th Edition 
[image: Circuit]

Comment: Your specific confusion appears to be undocumented.

Comment: I'm confused about the definition of power. It would make sense to use the voltage across the resistance not the voltage across both the resistor and the capacitor aka the node voltage

Comment: IIRC, the power absorbed in / dissipated by the resistor is the AC voltage through the resistor times the AC current through the resistor times the cosine of the phase angle between the voltage and current.

Comment: Power in a resistor is indeed ALWAYS calculated from the voltage drop across it.

Comment: If you are correct SuperGeo then the book is wrong then.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the voltage at the node, you could use a voltage divider to find the voltage across the resistor and get the power that way.  You can also calculate the complex power using the voltage at the node and the current through the series 2 Ohm resistor and capacitor branch.  The real part of the complex power is the average power, which is what is absorbed by the resistor.  Both calculations should give the same result.  Unless told otherwise, the voltages and currents in the circuit are going to be peak values at some phase angle that will come out of the analysis.  You will need to divide the current and voltage by the square root of two to get the RMS power in the resistor.